# AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'dialect'

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to create table in database as this is my connection as the below code:

```
# pyodbc connection connect to server
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "driver={SQL Server};server=xxxxxxxxxxx; database=master; trusted_connection=true",
    autocommit=True, Trusted_Connection='Yes')
crsr = conn.cursor()

# connect db (connect to database name) using SQL-Alchemy

engine = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://xxxxxxxxxxx/master?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
connection = engine.connect()
```

it's just a `pyodbc` conncetion

and this is the error I found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/ToolUpdated/app.py", line 22, in <module>
    dfeed_gsm_relation_m.push_dfeed_gsm_relation_sql()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\ToolUpdated\meta_data\dfeed_gsm_relation_m.py", line 31, in push_dfeed_gsm_relation_sql
    if connec.crsr.dialect.has_table(connec.crsr, DATAF_GSM_RELATION):
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'dialect'
```

and this is the code that creates the table in the database using `MetaData()`:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, Date, Float
from database import connec
import sqlalchemy as db
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from txt_to_csv import convert_to_csv
import os

def push_dfeed_gsm_relation_sql():
    # Create a ditionary for all gsm_relations_mnm relation excel file
    dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict = {
        'cell_name': 'Cellname',
        'n_cell_name': 'Ncellname',
        'technology': 'Technology',
    }
    # table name in database 'df_gsm_relation'
    DATAF_GSM_RELATION = 'df_gsm_relation'

    # Create a list for dataf_gsm_relation_cols and put the dictionary in the list
    dataf_gsm_relation_cols = list(dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict.keys())

    dataf_gsm_relation_cols_meta = MetaData()
    dataf_gsm_relation_relations = Table(
        DATAF_GSM_RELATION, dataf_gsm_relation_cols_meta,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column(dataf_gsm_relation_cols[0], Integer),
        Column(dataf_gsm_relation_cols[1], Integer),
        Column(dataf_gsm_relation_cols[2], String),
    )

    if connec.crsr.dialect.has_table(connec.crsr, DATAF_GSM_RELATION):
        dataf_gsm_relation_relations.drop(connec.crsr)
    dataf_gsm_relation_cols_meta.create_all(connec.crsr)

    dataf_gsm_rel_txt = 'gsmrelation_mnm.txt'
    dataf_gsm_txt_df = pd.read_csv(dataf_gsm_rel_txt, sep=';')
    dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index = list(dataf_gsm_txt_df.columns)
    dataf_gsm_txt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    dataf_gsm_txt_df.drop(columns=dataf_gsm_txt_df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
    dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index = dict(zip(list(dataf_gsm_txt_df.columns), dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index))
    dataf_gsm_txt_df.rename(columns=dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index, inplace=True)
    dataf_gsm_txt_df.to_excel('gsmrelation_mnm.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)

    dataf_gsm_rel_excel = 'gsmrelation_mnm.csv'

    dataf_gsm_rel_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dataf_gsm_rel_excel), dtype={
        dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict[dataf_gsm_relation_cols[0]]: int,
        dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict[dataf_gsm_relation_cols[1]]: int,
        dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict[dataf_gsm_relation_cols[2]]: str,
    })

    dataf_gsm_relations_table_query = db.insert(dataf_gsm_relation_relations)
    dataf_gsm_relations_values_list = []
    dataf_gsm_relations_row_count = 1
    for i in dataf_gsm_rel_df.index:
        dataf_gsm_relations_row = dataf_gsm_rel_df.loc[i]
        dataf_gsm_rel_df_record = {'id': dataf_gsm_relations_row_count}
        for col in dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict.keys():
            if col == dataf_gsm_relation_cols[0] or col == dataf_gsm_relation_cols[1]:
                dataf_gsm_rel_df_record[col] = int(dataf_gsm_relations_row[dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict[col]])
            else:
                dataf_gsm_rel_df_record[col] = dataf_gsm_relations_row[dataf_gsm_relation_col_dict[col]]
        dataf_gsm_relations_values_list.append(dataf_gsm_rel_df_record)
        dataf_gsm_relations_row_count += 1
    ResultProxy_dataf_gsm_relations = connec.crsr.execute(dataf_gsm_relations_table_query,
                                                     dataf_gsm_relations_values_list)
```

as the problem in this part:

```
    if connec.crsr.dialect.has_table(connec.crsr, DATAF_GSM_RELATION):
        dataf_gsm_relation_relations.drop(connec.crsr)
    dataf_gsm_relation_cols_meta.create_all(connec.crsr)
```

I know `dialect` function is related to `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` and this is my old connection as I changed to new connection using `import pyodbc` .....

So how can I solve this case using `pyodbc` module?

## Edited

The other way to solve this is how to `CREATE` and `DROP` table in existing `database` using `SQL ALCHEMY`

and this is the related code example:

```
from database import connec

def create_db():
    create_bd_query = "CREATE DATABASE MyNewDatabase"
    connec.crsr.execute(create_bd_query)

def delete_database():
    delete_bd_query = "DROP DATABASE MyNewDatabase"
    connec.crsr.execute(delete_bd_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just import a completley different module and expect it to be the same :)

Dialects are what SQLalchemy uses to communicate to different drivers.

In this instance Pyodbc IS the driver so it has no need for a dialect.

From SQLAlchemy:

> [**Dialects**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/)
>
> The dialect is the system SQLAlchemy uses to communicate with various types of DBAPI implementations and databases. The sections that follow contain reference documentation and notes specific to the usage of each backend, as well as notes for the various DBAPIs.
>
> *All dialects require that an appropriate DBAPI driver is installed.*
>
> **Included Dialects**
>
> PostgreSQL
>
> MySQL
>
> SQLite
>
> Oracle
>
> Microsoft SQL Server

---

> [**Microsoft SQL Server**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html)
>
> Support for the Microsoft SQL Server database.
>
> **DBAPI Support**
>
> The following dialect/DBAPI options are available. Please refer to individual 
>   DBAPI sections for connect information.
>
> PyODBC
>
> mxODBC
>
> pymssql
>
> zxJDBC for Jython
>
> adodbapi

Judging from the error and by looking at the [PyODBC Wiki Documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)

I think this line:

```
if connec.crsr.dialect.has_table(connec.crsr, DATAF_GSM_RELATION):
```

should read:

```
# Does table 'DATAF_GSM_RELATION' exist?
if connec.crsr.tables(table=DATAF_GSM_RELATION).fetchone():
    ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer so you mean that I'll not use the `connec.crsr` any more?

Comment: the problem is the code working fine with this conection string `mssql+pyodbc://xxxxxxxxxxx/toolDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0` and all the code works with this connection `engine = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://WINKPN-3B5JTT2\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/master?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
connection = engine.connect()
    # engine = pydoc.connect('mssql+pyodbc://WINKPN-3B5JTT2\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/toolDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0', autocommit=True)`

Comment: could you check the Edit?

Comment: It is only the dialect part that needs to be removed and changing to the `tables` function.  That being said your code will be much easier to manage, cleaner and readble with the edited solution.

Comment: ok If I remove the dialect part and I got `AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute '_run_visitor'` :(

Comment: All the functions you can use with a pyodbc cursor are here (link is also in the answer) https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor

Comment: alsoo in the answer is the line you have to change..  if connec.crsr.tables(table=DATAF_GSM_RELATION).fetchone():

Comment: as outlined in the documentation... if you make a change and it does not work, please edit your question.. Also please read the answer carefully and take it in.